# Run Ruby script without invoking it directly

Tags: ruby, bash

I'm looking for solution how can run Ruby script without invoking it directly like

```
ruby /path/to/file.rb
```

So far, I have been using aliases in my `.bashrc` to create shortcut like

```
alias myscript='ruby /path/to/file.rb'
```

But now, I need to create a gem which I'd like to use on different computers and my current approach doesn't fit well for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you could do is the following:

1. Create a shell script which invokes the Ruby script as your alias does:

   ```
   ruby /path/to/file.rb
   ```
2. Set a softlink to the /usr/bin/ path to invoke it in the shell using `somecommand`:

   ```
   ln -s /full/path/to/the/previously/created/shellscript /usr/bin/somecommand
   ```
3. If you wanna go further, you could create a shell script which does the soft-linking automatically.

Answer (score 2):

Add a shebang to the beginning of the script

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
```

(check that shebang is #!)
then make your script executable

```
chmod +x file.rb
```

Now you can run the file as a "standalone" executable

```
# For example
$ ./file.rb
```

("Standalone", because the ruby interpreter still needs to be installed somewhere in your path.)